# Max power of 2 such that 2^m divides n. (The ruler sequence)

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence

#### Input:

A positive integer **N**.

#### Challenge:

Suppose you have a list of integers **n = 1, 2 ... N**. Output a list of integers, where each number is the maximum power of 2, **m**, such that **2^m** divides each number of **n**.

---

Test cases:

```
1
0

15
0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0

100
0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 6, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 2
```

This is [OEIS A007814](https://oeis.org/A007814).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/126172/41024) or [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/68978/41024) (although both ask for more than just the sequence).

Comment: Using the sandbox helps too :)

Comment: [Also related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/63629/194)

Comment: @StewieGriffin Is returning floats allowed? E.g.: `[0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]`

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder no the question specifies integers. It doesn't matter what datatype the numbers have, as long as they're displayed as integers. (Relevant for MATLAB / Octave since they treat all numbers as [doubles by default](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/UcFWwZCrPCO/WCHx/38A)).

Comment: Can I print each integer on a new line?

Comment: @RobertoGraham I am almost 100% sure Stewie will say yes - most code-golf challenges have flexible IO unless there is good reason to restrict it, any easily parsable and consistent delimitation in your output should be fine.

Comment: @RobertoGraham yes, optional output format. :-)

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 46 bytes

Saved a couple of bytes thanks to [nwellnhof](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9296/nwellnhof).

```python
lambda k:[len(bin(t+1&~t))-3for t in range(k)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHbKjonNU8jKTNPo0TbUK2uRFNT1zgtv0ihRCEzT6EoMS89VSNbM/Z/QVFmXolGmoahpiYXnG2KzDEw0NT8DwA)

---

**[Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 51 bytes**

```python
lambda k:[len(bin(t-~-(t&-~t)))-3for t in range(k)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHbKjonNU8jKTNPo0S3TlejRE23rkRTU1PXOC2/SKFEITNPoSgxLz1VI1sz9n9BUWZeiUaahqGmJhecbYrMMTDQ1PwPAA)

## How?

The formula for **a(k)** is **log<sub>2</sub>(k - (k & (k - 1)))**. That's quite fluffy, but fortunately it can be shortened significantly. In Python, **floor(log<sub>2</sub>(N)) = len(bin(N)) - 3**, because `bin()` appends `0b` to the binary representation of an integer. As a side note, `len(bin(N))-3` can be replaced by `N.bit_length()-1`, but that is not really beneficial for golfing purposes. That gives us the opportunity to get rid of the `import math` and the use of `math.log`. Another part that can be shortened is **k & (k-1)**. Using more bitwise operations, we get **k&~-k** instead, and then we subtract this from the actual **k**. But that would make us iterate over the range **[1, k]**, which would waste bytes because Python lacks inclusive ranges. In order to save a few bytes, we iterate over the integers in **[0, k)** instead and modify the formula, obtaining **k+1-(k&-~k) = k-~-(k&-~k)**. However, than can be simplified further to **k+1&~k** (as  @nwellnhof pointed out).

Comment: FWIW `t+1-(t&-~t)` is the same length with less tadpoles.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Heh, I wonder how I missed that. I still like tildes and I will keep it that way though.

Comment: Or simply `bin(t+1&~t)`.

Answer (score 8):

## Pyth, 6 bytes

```
m/Pd2S
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=m%2FPd2S&input=5&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A15%0A100&debug=0)

#### Explanation:

```
m/Pd2S
     S   range [1, 2, ..., input]
m        map each number to
 /  2       the count of two in
  Pd        its prime factorization
```

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, 29 bytes

```
#~IntegerExponent~2&~Array~#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvtfuc4zryQ1PbXItaIgPy81r6TOSK3OsagosbJOWe1/QFFmXomCQ1q0oYFB7P//AA)

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>60</s> <s>59</s> <s>55</s> 40 bytes

```r
n=1:scan();cat(log2(n-(bitwAnd(n,n-1))))
```

Reads from stdin, writes to stdout. Implements the formula referenced in [Mr.
Xcoder's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141852/67312), which fortunately vectorizes nicely in R.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8/W0Ko4OTFPQ9M6ObFEIyc/3UgjT1cjKbOk3DEvRSNPJ0/XUBMI/hua/QcA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 29 bytes

```hs
($l).take
l=0:do x<-l;[x+1,0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P8fWwColX6HCRjfHOrpC21DHIJYrzVZDJUdTryQxO/V/bmJmnoKtQko@l4JCQVFmXomCikKagiEqzxSVa2DwHwA)

Recursively generate the infinite list `l`.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>42</s> 39 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to [@Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy)*

A straight-forward version using [Math.clz32()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/clz32). Returns a comma-delimited string.

```js
f=n=>--n&&f(n)+[,31-Math.clz32(++n&-n)]
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=n=>--n&&f(n)+[,31-Math.clz32(++n&-n)]

console.log(f(1))
console.log(f(15))
console.log(f(100))
```

---

## Alternate version, <s>42</s> 41 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to [@Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy)*

```js
f=n=>--n&&f(n)+[,(g=n=>n&1&&1+g(n/2))(n)]
```

#### How?

This is based on the recursive formula:

```
a(n) =
  0 if n is odd
  a(n / 2) + 1 if n is even
```

For golfing purposes, the function ***g*** is actually doing almost the opposite:

```
g(n) =
  g(n / 2) + 1 if the least significant bit of n is set
  0 if the least significant bit of n is clear
```

We do it that way because ***n*** has already been decremented when ***g*** is invoked, so it's off by 1. This generates floats, but testing the LSB rather than computing a modulo ensures that the decimal part is ignored.

The function ***f*** is just a wrapper that invokes ***g*** for all values from ***n - 1*** to ***1***, appending the results in reverse order, and eventually appending a leading ***0*** when the recursion stops.

#### Test cases

```js
f=n=>--n&&f(n)+[,(g=n=>n&1&&1+g(n/2))(n)]

console.log(f(1))
console.log(f(15))
console.log(f(100))
```

Comment: This should work for 41 bytes: `f=n=>--n&&f(n)+[,(g=n=>n&1&&1+g(n/2))(n)]` and applying the same trick to your alt. reduces it to 39 bytes: `f=n=>--n&&f(n)+[,31-Math.clz32(++n&-n)]`.

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>49</s> 44 bytes

```c
f(n){n-1&&f(n-1);printf("%.f ",log2(n&-n));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcnBCoAgDADQc36FBMkGLbSrXxPSJLAVVqfo11vdHrxEOSVVBsFbKDj3iwLGvS5yMrTdwLbty5ZHEEeCGB/9x67TIoD2Ng1D8B6jaep8XlWsj@bRN3GZ8qFU1g8)

Answer (score 5):

## x86 Machine Code, 10 bytes

```
0F BC C1
49
89 04 8A
75 F7
C3
```

The above bytes of machine code define a function that takes an array of length *n* as input, and then replaces the value at each index with the maximum power of 2, *m*, such that 2<sup>m</sup> divides each number of *n*. each number is the maximum power of 2, m, such that 2^m divides each number of n.

It follows the [`__fastcall`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_fastcall) register-based calling convention, passing the first parameter (the length of the array, *n*) in the `ECX` register and the second parameter (a pointer to the beginning of the array) in the `EDX` register. I posit that this is legal because, [like C](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13210/list-input-in-c-and-length-argument), arrays/lists are represented at the machine-code level as a pointer to the first element and a length.

As stipulated in the challenge, *n* is assumed to be a strictly positive integer.

**Ungolfed assembly mnemonics:**

```
                ; void RulerSequence(unsigned len, unsigned * pSequence);
                ;                                     ECX  = len
                ;                                     EDX  = pSequence
             Top:
0F BC C1        bsf   eax, ecx                      ; EAX  = log2(ECX)
49              dec   ecx                           ; ECX -= 1
89 04 8A        mov   DWORD PTR [edx+ecx*4], eax    ; pSequence[ECX] = EAX
75 F7           jnz   Top                           ; loop to 'Top' if ECX != 0
C3              ret
```

As you can see, the logic is embarrassingly simple. The only thing even slightly tricky is the use of [the `BSF` instruction](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_19.html), which obtains the index of the least-significant set bit. This is the shortest and fastest way to compute log<sub>2</sub>(n).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDbTsMwDH1uvsIqQkpZBi27U0AaE3viD5apCmm6RepS1KYogPbrFBfYKIgHy5Z9fM6xZX8jZdPIwlQW5FaU4KbjRZGq1RpuwOcuXHJ3t@BuEXE3nHE3xQiHmOfcTUbcLSc4G/gxqaywWsJzoVNIEmFtqR9rq5KE0kxUVoo8DwKgZ8i/dCagtan0xqiUwaE6C1DyWz5uTrSReZ0quK5sqovz7S0hByRYVdl5WYoXtIlLbxAxuGQwYDBkMGIwZjBhMGUwYxCFGDiPEBAhIkJINIJ9/A/dgzJIV@lXVWT02A0u/nZW4TqICdHGwk5oQwPyRryvy2iXjP1Qt3jvqcSVjPpzaWuRX3HLrY8DLytKoC2bRvkwxnT9y1QMvZ4OiIcqR45TfJ3fEVjp1pO378hwc@@elLQqRan2DQzCz0cd60Gn7vT9T7elsnVp0A/ZN@8yy8Wmavq7weUH)**

---

**Bonus alternate solution, also 10 bytes**

```
                ; void RulerSequence_Alt(unsigned len, unsigned * pSequence);
                ;     ECX = len
                ;     EDX = pSequence
             Top:
0F BC C1        bsf   eax, ecx
89 44 8A FC     mov   DWORD PTR [edx+ecx*4-4], eax
E2 F7           loop  Top
C3              ret
```

Instead of separate `DEC`+`JNZ` instructions, we use the long-obsolete CISC-style `LOOP` instruction, which decrements `ECX` and loops to the specified label as long as `ECX` != 0. `LOOP` takes the same 2 bytes to encode as `JNZ`, so this saves us 1 byte from `DEC`. However, to compensate for the decrement being done *after* the array offset calculation, we need to add an additional subtraction to the indexing, which costs us an additional byte. So it's a wash.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
RÆEḢ€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/ocJvrwx2LHjWt@f//v6EpAA)

*Saved 1 byte thanks to [miles](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/6710/miles)!

Definitely not as short as the [built-in answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141845/59487) with *Order, multiplicity, valuation*, but I think it's worth it posting.

## How?

```
RÆEḢ€  - Full program.

R      - The range [1, input].
 ÆE    - Compute the array of exponents of the prime factorization, including 0's.
    €  - For €ach.
   Ḣ   - Head. 
       - Implicitly output the result.
```

Comment: There's also an atom `ÆE` which gives the exponent of each prime factor, making `RÆEḢ€`

Comment: @miles Cool, thanks

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
†#2†pḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HDAmUjIFHwcMfi////G5oCAA)

## How?

It's my first "non-trivial" attempt in Husk, so patient with me :-)

```
†#2†pḣ   - Full program.

     ḣ   - The range [1, input].
   †p    - Map with prime factorisation.
†#2      - Count the 2's in each.
         - Implicitly output.
```

[Alternative](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P1fZKLfg4Y7F////NzQFAA), suggested by [Erik the Outgolfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41024/erik-the-outgolfer): `m#2mpḣ`.

Comment: Seems optimal to me, had `m#2mpḣ`.

Comment: Or `mo#2pḣ`. Two `m`s seems wasteful

Comment: @H.PWiz `o` is confusing though, you're probably lucky it works there...

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer, not lucky. It's fairly standard function composition

Answer (score 4):

## C, 48 bytes

Using GCC's [builtin to count trailing zeros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.4.0/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-_005f_005fbuiltin_005fctz):

```c
f(v,n)int*v;{while(n--)v[n]=__builtin_ctz(n+1);}
```

Input in integer `n`, and output to the supplied array `v` (which must be at least `n` long).

### Test program:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    while (*++argv) {
        int n = atoi(*argv);
        if (n>0) {
            int *v = malloc(sizeof *v * n);
            if (!v) continue;
            f(v,n);
            printf("\n%d:\n", n);
            for (int i = 0;  i < n;  ++i)
                printf("%d ", v[i]);
            free(v);
            puts("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. Using an array is better than my `printf` approach. Combined with my new `log2` solution, you could get this to [40 bytes](https://tio.run/##FYtBDoMgFETXcgpi0waqNLRbtBcxLgyK/gS/DSpdGK9eCqt5kzejxah1CIZh6Tngdvfq@E5gB4bcN0JgW9tlfDG8CeTqDBdAbfd@oNW69bA8pjch8UbnDpBxepAsNd88pWwVyQyLUFLPEy@OsmShlopCFU2MouAkyz4uCsPya0/zOG@gTQ83bLtDKhU5w08b241rEHb@Aw).

Comment: Was that link supposed to point at some code?  Or are we supposed to follow one of the links (which one?).  It would probably be simpler to show what you meant in a comment...

Comment: I have doubts about `log2()` - it needs to be passed a `double`, or to be declared, both of which cost more bytes than would be saved.

Comment: Yes, this only works because `log2` is a gcc builtin. Also the predecrement is technically undefined behavior. But the general rule for code golf is that the language implementation counts, not the spec.

Comment: I forgot that `log2` is builtin in GCC - that really helps!  Where's the predecrement you're referring to?  I have a postdecrement (`n--`).

Comment: I mean the predecrement in my [TIO code](https://tio.run/##FYtBDoMgFETXcgpi0waqNLRbtBcxLgyK/gS/DSpdGK9eCqt5kzejxah1CIZh6Tngdvfq@E5gB4bcN0JgW9tlfDG8CeTqDBdAbfd@oNW69bA8pjch8UbnDpBxepAsNd88pWwVyQyLUFLPEy@OsmShlopCFU2MouAkyz4uCsPya0/zOG@gTQ83bLtDKhU5w08b241rEHb@Aw).

Comment: Where's the code? `tryitonline.github.io gitter.im/tryitonline talk.tryitonline.net @Try_It_Online Try It Online 1TryittLK3yAScCKavr5pg1eCZgpTdqYH direct link Linode` doesn't mean much to GCC, and there's nothing else visible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65186/discussion-between-nwellnhof-and-toby-speight).

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
ọ€2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///h7t5HTWuM/v//b2gKAA)

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>86 + 26</s> <s>75</s> <s>81</s> <s>79</s> <s>77</s> <s>76</s> 74 bytes

```
n->{for(int i=0;i<n;System.out.println(n.toString(++i&-i,2).length()-1));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY4xb8IwEIX3/IqbkF0aq1RiMrB0YmBiRB1c46SXOmfLPiMhlN@emjZvu@/p9L7B3EwboqPh@jPjGENiGCpThdGrrpBlDKRedNPE8uXRgvUmZzgZJHg0UJPZcOUfgXIZXdodiV3v0gG6PczUHh5dSAKJAfdvGnekz/fMblShsIqpFp4EKQ5nrkcv1mtctfj6LpV31PO3kO1GSj3NVeE5t2gsq7eAVxirjPh/v3yCSX2Wi9sznTLWushis5X6j07NNP8C)

Comment: Apparently you aren't allowed to output floats/doubles and have to output integers, so `Math.log(i&-i++)/Math.log(2)` should be `(int)(Math.log(i&-i++)/Math.log(2))` instead. One thing you can golf however: `i<n+1` can be `i<=n`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>42</s> 37 bytes

*5 bytes removed thanks to [@StewieGriffin!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31516/stewie-griffin)*

```matlab
@(n)([~,y]=max(mod(x=1:n,2.^x')>0))-1
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BI09TI7pOpzLWNjexQiM3P0WjwtbQKk/HSC@uQl3TzkBTU9fwf5qGoanmfwA)

#### Explanation

Let `n` be the input. The code computes each number `k` in the range `1`, ..., `n` modulo each number `d` in `1`, `2`, `4`, ..., `2^n`. This gives an `n`×`n` matrix, where `k` is the column index and each `d` corresponds to a row.

This matrix is compared for inequality with 0. As a result, nonzeros are transformed into `1`, and zeros remain as `0`.

For each column `k`, finding the (1-based) row index of the maximum value and subtracting 1 gives the solution. In other words, the number of initial zeros in each column is the desired `m` for each `k`.

Comment: [**37**](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BI09TI7pOpzLWNjexQiM3P0WjwtbQKk/HSC@uQl3TzkBTU9fwf5qGoZnmfwA)

Comment: @StewieGriffin Huh, I didn't know that could be done. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 29 bytes

```
n->[valuation(x,2)|x<-[1..n]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8D9P1y66LDGnNLEkMz9Po0LHSLOmwkY32lBPLy829n9BUWZeiUaahqGBgabmfwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

Patched a bug thanks to [Emigna](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/47066/emigna) (`Ý` -> `L`).

```
LÒε2¢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f5/Ckc1uNDi36/9/QFAA)

## How?

```
LÒε2¢   - Full program.

L       - The range [1, input].
 Ò      - Prime factors with duplicates.
  ε     - For εach.
   2¢   - Count the 2's.
        - Output (implicitly).
```

Alternative:

```
LεÒ2¢
```

Answer (score 3):

## Japt, 7 bytes

A port of [Jakube's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141854/58974).

```
õ_k è¶2
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=9V9rIOi2Mg==&input=MTU=)

---

### Explanation

Implicit input of integer `U`.

```
õ_
```

Generate an array of integers from 1 to `U` and pass each through a function.

```
k
```

Get an array of the prime factors of the current element.

```
è¶2
```

Count (`è`) the number of elements that are strictly equal to (`¶`) 2.

Comment: `õ_k` +1 for cute faces.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 34 bytes

```
.+
$*
\B1
¶$`1
+`(1+)\1
$+0
%r`0\G
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRYsrxsmQ69A2lQRDLu0EDUNtzRhDLhVtAy7VogSDGPf//w1NAQ) Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
\B1
¶$`1
```

Create a triangle.

```
+`(1+)\1
$+0
```

Start converting each row to base 2...

```
%r`0\G
```

...but instead of completing the conversion, just count the trailing zeros.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), <s>27</s> <s>17</s> 15 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to [Brad Gilbert b2gills](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/1147/brad-gilbert-b2gills)

```perl6
{(1..$_)».lsb}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJKmYPu/WsNQT08lXvPQbr2c4qTa/8WJIAkNQwMDTev/AA)

Comment: `{(1..$_)».lsb}` / `{(1..$_)>>.lsb}`

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 36 bytes

```
a 0=[0]
a n|q<-a$n-1=q++n:q
take<*>a
```

An adaption of [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/69010/34531) from a [similar challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/68978/34531).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P1HBwDbaIJYrUSGvptBGN1ElT9fQtlBbO8@qkCvNtiQxO9VGyy7xf25iZp6CrUJKPpeCQkFRZl6JgopCmoIhKs8UlWtg8B8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 9 bytes

```
msl-hd.&h
```

**[Verify the test cases.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=msl-hd.%26h&input=5&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A15%0A100&debug=0)**

If returning as floats was allowed, then **8 bytes**:

```
ml-hd.&h
```

## Explanation

```
msl-hd.&h  - Full program. Q means input.

m          - Map over the implicit range [0, Q) with a variable d.
 sl        - The integer part of logarithm base 2 of...
   -hd.&h  - ... The Logical OR between d and d + 1, subtracted from d + 1.
           - Output implicitly.
```

The formula for **a(k)** is **log<sub>2</sub>(k - (k & (k - 1)))**, if we were to work with **[1, Q]**. By mapping over **[0, Q)** instead, we modify the formula accordingly, **log<sub>2</sub>(k + 1 - (k & (k + 1))**. This allows us to abuse implicit ranges at the end of the program.

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 6 bytes

```
/R2PMS
```

An alternative to [Jakube's approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141854/59487).

```
/R2PMS   - Full program. Q means input.

     S   - The range [1, Q].
   PM    - Get prime factors of each.
/R2      - Count the number of 2's.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 10 bytes

```
mlec.Bd\1S
```

[Try it here.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=mlec.Bd%5C1S&input=15&debug=0)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 5 bytes

Port of [Jakube's Pyth answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141854/59487), and [my 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141859/59487).

```
SFP2/
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=SFP2%2F&input=100&warnings=0&hex=0)

## How?

```
S     - The range [1, input]
 F    - For each.
  P   - Prime factors.
   2/ - Count the number of 2's.
      - Output implicitly.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 10 bytes

```
_{.@q:1+i.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P03B1kohvlrPodDKUDtTj4srNTkjXyFNwdD0/38A)

### Explanation

```
_{.@q:1+i.  Input: n
        i.  Range, [0, n)
      1+    Add 1
_   q:      Exponents of each prime in the factorization of each
 {.@        Head each (Get the exponent of 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 50 + 2 bytes

```
perl -E'say+sprintf("%b",$_)=~s/.*1//r=~y===c for 1..shift'
```

50 bytes for the program proper, and 2 for the command line switch.

The largest m such that 2^m divides n is just the number of trailing 0s in the binary representation of n. We get the latter by removing everything up to the last 1 of the binary representation, and taking the length of that. `y===c` happens to do that (it replaces every character by itself, returning the number characters it replaced).